# What is the meaning of Srimad Bhagvad Gita 3.26?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, explanation

I have  some confusion in Gita  chapter 3, Verse 26.

[Source](http://shlokam.org/bhagavad-gita/3-26/)

> na buddhibhedaṃ janayedajñānāṃ karmasaṅginām
> joṣayetsarvakarmāṇi vidvānyuktaḥ samācaran

> Meaning:Let no wise-man unsettle the minds of ignorant-people, who are attached to action; he should engage them in all actions, himself fulfilling them with devotion.

My confusion: **no wise-man unsettle the minds of ignorant-people  and he should engage them in all actions**

It  means, the wise  should not disturb the mind  of  ignorant people   and  they  should inspire/encourage  them to do  all action

How it can be  possible if  we inspire  the ignorant  to do all good  action? Then definitely their   mind  will get disturbed.

My understanding is that  by inspiring/encouraging  the ignorant, it means, to disturb the mind  of ignorant people.

I'm  not getting  the meaning of this  verse.

Comment: https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/26      read this, it has commentary too & to understand shloka 26 read 27 & 28 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gita says:

> Let him (jnani) not unsettle the minds of the ignorant who are
> attached to action. The enlightened man doing all works in a spirit of
> yoga, should set others to act as well.

**Gita 3.26**

This verse is talking of the enlightened who has attained his objective of God or Self realization. He has no work left to do. Also God reduces the work of such a man.

> M: "How long must one do one's duty?"
>
> MASTER: "The blossom drops off when the fruit appears. One doesn't
> have to do one's duty after the attainment of God, nor does one feel
> like doing it then.
>
> "If a drunkard takes too much liquor he cannot retain consciousness.
> If he takes only two or three glasses, he can go on with his work. **As
> you advance nearer and nearer to God, He will reduce your activities
> little by little. Have no fear.**
>
> "Finish the few duties you have at hand, and then you will have peace.
> When the mistress of the house goes to bathe after finishing her
> cooking and other household duties, she won't come back, however you
> may shout after her."

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 4, Advice to Householders**

**What should such a man do?**

Gita is saying that such a man should continue working to set an example to the unenlightened. What will happen if the enlightened person stops working completely? Then an unenlightened or ignorant person might just copy the enlightened person by not working which will harm the unenlightened person.